# How to contain formulas within a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested

I am trying to have formula return with a cell population with the first six characters of the look up cell given that the first two characters are 10.

See below for example.

```
=IF((LEFT(A3,2)=10), LEFT(A3,6), "")
```

As of right now, I keep getting a blank return no matter the look up cell's information.

Comment: LEFT applies to string, so you need to wrap 10 in double quotes ...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`=IF(LEFT(A3,2)="10",LEFT(A3,6),"")`

`LEFT` returns a text string so you need `"`. You also don't need the double brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can aslo force the result of left() to be numerical,

```
=IF(LEFT(A3,2)*1=10,LEFT(A3,6),"")
```

I used *1, but +0 can work.

see

[image]

This can be convenient if you want to have the values like 10 or 15 etc in separate cells so you can just drag down.

See

[image]

You could use a cell to tell left() how many characters to collect or use the len() function.